# How to add multiple error messages to a JsError without using a var

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6

In the following function, I am parsing a `json`. I want to return `JsError` which describes all the errors (if any) in the `json`. But I am unable to figure out how to keep changing the `JsError` without using a `var`. I am looking for a more `functional` way of writing the code.

```
implicit object PQReads extends Reads[PQ] {
  def reads(json:JsValue):JsResult[PQ]  =  {

    val id = (json \ "id").asOpt[UUID]
    val d = (json \ "d").asOpt[String]
    val h = (json \"h").asOpt[List[String]]
    val i  = (json \ "i").asOpt[List[String]] 

   //HERE I WANT TO ADD LOGIC TO CHECK THAT ALL THE OPTIONS ARE DEFINED.
   //THE ONES WHICH ARE NONE SHOULD BE INDICATED BACK IN JSERROR
   // (EG D AND I FIELDS ARE MISSING). HOW DO I DO THIS WITHOUT
   // USING VAR TYPE FOR JSERROR.
   //IF ALL THE FIELDS ARE PRESENT THEN I'LL RETURN PQ INSTANCE IN JSSUCCESS
}
```

Comment: @cchantep, I don't think it is really fair to ask the "what have you tried" this time. To "try by oneself" means to reinvent the validation applicative. And Googling is really unhelpful when one does not even know the name of the concept. In fact I applaud the asker's ability to feel "there's a better way" and to ask the question.

Comment: The usual way I would do it is to check which field is empty and then using `if` conditions, I can construct an error message. I am not sure though if that is the best way to do it as the code will not be concise. Thus I thought to check if there is a better (functional) way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

I have not used Play for quite some time, but I don't think you have to do the reading manually.

When you have `case class PQ(id: UUID, d :String, h: List[String], i: List[String])`
,
you can simply write `implicit val pqReads = Json.reads[PQ]`.
See [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaJsonAutomated) for the documentation on the automated mapping.

But if you really want to do it yourself, take a look at the [reading combinators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Reads).

```
implicit val pqReads: Reads[PQ] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").read[UUID] and
  (JsPath \ "d").read[String] and
  (JsPath \ "h").read[List[String]] and
  (JsPath \ "i").read[List[String]]
)(PQ.apply _)
```

---

For the conversions,

```
val validJson = Json.parse("""
{
  "id": "586c154d-1e0f-428c-97bc-200dec9328bb",
  "d": "d",
  "h": ["h", "i"],
  "i": []
}
""")

println(validJson.validate[PQ])

val invalidJson = Json.parse("""
{
  "id": "586c154d-1e0f-428c-97bc-200dec9328bb",
  "d": "d",
  "h": 123
}
""")

println(invalidJson.validate[PQ])
```

both of the `implicit val`s provide the same result.

```
JsSuccess(PQ(586c154d-1e0f-428c-97bc-200dec9328bb,d,List(h, i),List()),)
JsError(List((/i,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))), (/h,List(JsonValidationError(List(error.expected.jsarray),WrappedArray())))))
```

Comment: The reason I am extending `Reads` is so that I can customize the error messages

Answer (score 0):

With `play-json` I use always `case-classes`!

I simplified your problem to the essence:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
```

Define a case class

```
case class PQ(id:UUID, d:String, h:List[String], i: List[String])
```

Add a formatter in the companion `object`:

```
object PQ {
  implicit val jsonFormat: Format[PQ] = Json.format[PQ]
}
```

And use `validate`:

```
Json.parse(YOUR_JSON).validate[PQ] match {
  case JsSuccess(pq, _) => println(pq)
  case JSError(errors) => println(s"Handle exception $other") 
}
```

This returns either the PQ or a List with the errors. No need to do anything here.